# Getting error while using buildozer android debug for python Kivy app

Tags: python, kivy, apk, buildozer, android-debug

I'm trying to generate APK using Kivy buildozer and it end with
"Command failed: unzip -q /home/pandian/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/commandlinetools-linux-6514223_latest.zip".

Please correct me, where it went wrong.

[Error Log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFKWk.png)

**Here is the issue log:(added full error log screenshot)**

|# Command failed: unzip -q /home/pandian/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/commandlinetools-linux-6514223_latest.zip

|...

|...

|# Buildozer failed to execute the last command

|# The error might be hidden in the log above this error

|# Please read the full log, and search for it before

|# raising an issue with buildozer itself.

|# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
pandian@LAPTOP-LGPPPEDT:~/sudoku$**

Comment: Try running the command yourself. Does it fail? If so, how?

Comment: I ran "buildozer android debug" command. 
And it trigger "Run 'unzip -q /home/pandian/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/commandlinetools-linux-6514223_latest.zip'" 

Here i got a Command failed error. 
I have attached the "Error Log Screenshot" for your reference.

Comment: When I saw "running the command yourself" I mean run `unzip -q /home/pandian/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/commandlinetools-linux-6514223_latest.zip` directly, not through buildozer.

Comment: is unzip installed?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running it out side the venv as the default python is 2.7 so try to make a change to the python version using the command as follow

$sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.9 2 (latest version)

And then rerun
$ buildozer android debug